# determine the interval of convergence for $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I require help in making a distinct investigation of each end point for:

$(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$

And to determine its interval of convergence.

I used the ratio test for testing convergence or divergence.

And as a result I got:

$$-\frac{nx}{n+1}$$ However, I cannot seem to determine the end point. although, it seems to me that the series diverges, because of doing this:

$$-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\cdot x$$ as $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, then the series diverges.

Comment: I may have worded it poorly. I'm looking for the interval convergence, although the radius of convergence would be helpful too as I've yet to fully understand it.

Comment: "... as $1/n$ diverges, then the series diverges." ??? $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n) = 0$. Also important: the root test requires a series with positive terms.

Comment: **Sequence or series**?